# Error while installing watir-webdriver on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ruby, watir, functional-testing, watir-webdriver

After going step by step (installed both ruby and rubygems properly) to install watir-webdriver, I am facing following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing watir-webdriver:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Please help me resolve this and do let me know what made this happened?

Comment: First installing ruby and then rubygem using apt-get and after installing packages, when i try to install watir-webdriver as per instruction on (https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/blob/master/installation/ubuntu.md), it throws an error as mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you are installing ruby on your Ubuntu machine but may I recommend the Ruby Version Manager.

https://rvm.io/

this will allow you to install different versions of ruby on your machine and switch between them as well as gems etc.

here is a quick guide I wrote for installing watir webdriver in Ubuntu via RVM:

Ubuntu requires the use of a Ruby Version Manager. To do this we will need to first install both the Curl package and Git-core.

To do this use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install curl git-core
```

Upon success we will need to download the Ruby Version Manager application. This application allows us to install multiple versions of ruby as well as switch between. It also provides a Gem manger. Recommended to Google to read up on the commands and features within RVM. To install RVM use the following:

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
```

We can also install packages within RVM and we will require the use of openSSL:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
```

Then installing Ruby itself:

```
rvm install 1.9.3-p125 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Best to test this is all working with:

```
irb
```

When all clear we can install the Gem, we need to install it within the RVM with the follow:

```
rvm do gem install watir-webdriver
```

If installed correctly we should be able to use watir to drive firefox which is already installed on ubuntu.

Comment: - If rvm install 1.9.3-p125 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr throws an error (NoMethod_error) - then first update RVM and then install latest of Ruby (1.9.3-p194).
- For me rvm pkg was not working as it was asking to use command "package"
- instead of rvm do gem install watir-webdriver (it's been depricated), rvm all do gem install should be used

Comment: ah thank you for the info Fagun will add that to my notes. :)

Comment: i did step by step as written, and it worked... until i closed the terminal window. and now gem list doesnt even show watir. what the hell?

Answer (score 0):

I am not Linux/Ubuntu expert but the error message says you do not have build tools installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has been resolved now as simon's answer was great help!